# JBoss jaas session timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jaas

I want to set jaas session timeout in JBoss EAP 7.1.0. I defined the new security domain:

```
<security-domain name="management" cache-type="infinispan">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
            <module-option name="realm" value="ManagementRealm"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

and I modified the infinispan to set session timeout:

```
<cache-container name="security" default-cache="auth-cache">
    <local-cache name="auth-cache">
        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="1000"/>
        <expiration lifespan="120000" max-idle="60000"/>
    </local-cache>
</cache-container>
```

However, my jaas session never expires. In my application I have:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ManagementRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

and also my jboss-web.xml defines security domain:

```
<security-domain>management</security-domain>
```

JBoss asks me for password just once and afterwards it caches is so no login dialog is shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set *local-cache name* to the name of the security domain.

```
<local-cache name="management">
```

Comment: It didn't help. I got an error: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([ ("subsystem" => "security"), ("security-domain" => "other")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0369: Required capabilities are not available: org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.security"

Comment: Why did you get the error for security subsystem? Did you modify Local-cache name under infinispan susbsytem?

Comment: Yes - I modified <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">. Which one should I change?

Comment: for cache-container=security of the profile that you are using

Comment: This is what I have: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
 <cache-container name="security" default-cache="auth-cache">
  <local-cache name="auth-cache">
   <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="1000"/>
   <expiration lifespan="120000" max-idle="60000"/>
  </local-cache>
 </cache-container>
</subsystem>

Comment: Did you try changing local-cache name from "auth-cache" to "management"?

Comment: Yes. Also the mentioned exception

Comment: Ok. Let me check.